# Save image locally and display in webview

Tags: android, webview, save, local

I have trouble with this simple piece of code.
I download an image from the web and save it locally with :

```
               File mFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "a.png");
               if(!mFile.exists()) {         mFile.createNewFile();                }
               FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
               fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
               fos.flush();
               fos.close();
```

I try to display this image on the ImageView and it's working.
Now i try to **display the save image on a WebView.**

```
  String data = "<body>" +"<img src=\"a.png\"/></body>";
  webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(getActivity().getFilesDir().toString(),data , "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

It's not working, the webview shows nothing. I try the webview with a png i put myself in /assets and it's working.

I think my syntax to point to the file in the String data is wrong but i'm not sure.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Alex.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after testing lots of different things, i end up with this working code.

```
    WebView webview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);      

    try {
        FileInputStream in = getActivity().openFileInput("image_behindfragment.png");
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        byte[] bitMapA= new byte[buf.available()];
        buf.read(bitMapA);
        Bitmap bM = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitMapA, 0, bitMapA.length);
        //imageview.setImageBitmap(bM);
        if (in != null) {
        in.close();
        }
        if (buf != null) {
        buf.close();

        String imgToString = Base64.encodeToString(bitMapA,Base64.DEFAULT);
        String imgTag = "<img src='data:image/png;base64," + imgToString               
                + "' align='left' bgcolor='ff0000'/>"; 
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webview.setInitialScale(30);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);


        webview.loadData(imgTag, "text/html", "utf-8");

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
String imagePath = "file://"+ base + "/a.png";
String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///mnt/sdcard/Your Folder/", html, "text/html","utf-8", "");
```