# Display local android image in a webview using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, android-webview

Scene: I am trying to display a file image selected from the gallery into a webview using javascricpt and/or jquery but I am not able to do so. The same works while opening the html in a desktop browser.

What I have tried so far is this in the android code is this:

1. Written the `openFileChooser` code and getting the image path and also the image bytes.
2. calling the following in onActivityResult method:

   ```
   String js = "javascript:loadImage(file://" + imagePath + ")";
   mWebView.loadUrl(js);
   ```

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="file_chooser">
<!-- <input type="submit" value="File chooser" id="btnSubmit" onclick="sayHello();" > -->
<input type="file" name="banner_image" id="banner_image" onChange="loadImage(this);" accept="image/*" />

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

<img alt="" id="image" src=""  width="200px" height="200px" onclick="showSrc(this.src);">
</div>
```

and the javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadImage(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            Android.alert('input: ' + input.files[0]);
        var reader = new FileReader();


        reader.onload = (function(input) {
    return function(e) {
         $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        console.log('onload stage finished');
    };
})(input);
reader.onloadend = (function() {
    // $('#image').src(file.name);
});

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]); 

            //data:image/jpg;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -> this did not work
        }

  function showSrc(src) {
        Android.alert('src : ' + src);
    }
</script>
```

But i seem to be messing with the android code and also javascript, since i do not know jscript that well.

Please assist as to how to display an image after selection from the gallery.

**EDIT:**

I have gone through lotsa links that show how to call a javscript function from android , and how to display an image by calling loadBaseUrl with the new html code that has an image inside the src tag, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013504/save-image-locally-and-display-in-webview), but this is not what I really want.

Comment: Not sure but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10701366/1777090) might help.

Comment: @MysticMagic - thanks for the comment, but then this is what i dont want, the src is already predefined, but i would want something thats dynamic and set from javascript.

Comment: I am having a little confusion. Is this what you want to do? 1. Open a file chooser from javascript, 2. Pass selected image's path to android, 3. show that image in a webview.

Comment: @MysticMagic - yes thats correct. Open a file chooser, pick an image, get the path or bytes, pass it to javascript from android and then display it in the htnl file

Comment: ok, and you are able to pass the path to js correctly. right?

Comment: i think so.. @MysticMagic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61904/discussion-between-mysticmagic-and-rat-a-tat-a-tat-ratatouille).

Comment: Please do not edit your question and add "[Solved]". It invalidates the purpose of Stack Overflow as a "Q&A" site. Add your answer as an *answer*; you can even 'accept' it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who fall into such a case:
I changed how the loadImage method functions to one that converts a file received into bytes

Steps:
1. Read a file from android and send the path over to the js function
2. Pass the path to a reader and when the reader loads the file, the `onLoadEnd` method gets called
3. Convert the file to bytes using the code

```
var stringToReplace = reader.result;
stringToReplace = stringToReplace.replace('data:base64,','data:image\/jpeg;base64,');
```

4. Set the image source to the string obtained in #3.